# Smooth scroll foundation5 don't work

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation 5 magellan navigation but smooth scroll doesn't work. In example all is fine: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html

My code: http://jsfiddle.net/5LKzf/

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-5.2.2/css/foundation.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation-5.2.2/css/normalize.css" />
    <script src="css/foundation-5.2.2/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

//my link
    <li class="item-109 menu-el active"><dd data-magellan-arrival="/"><a href="#/" >Main Page</a></dd></li>


//my anhor
   <a class="link-pos" data-magellan-destination="/" name="/">&nbsp;</a>

  <script src="css/foundation-5.2.2/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="css/foundation-5.2.2/js/vendor/fastclick.js"></script>
        <script src="css/foundation-5.2.2/js/foundation.min.js"></script>    

        <script>
            $( document ).foundation();
        </script>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

Did I forget to include any files?

Comment: You have two types of Jquery, maybe there are some conflit. Check in your inspect console

Comment: No, i don't have any errors on console, also when i delete second jquery nothing change

Comment: Hmmm...i suppose you forgot include the foundation.magellan.js

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs

"*Make sure jquery.js, foundation.js, and foundation.magellan.js have been included on your page before continuing. For example, add the following before the closing  tag:*"

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.magellan.js"></script>
```

According to the code you posted, you are missing the magellan js, which would explain why it doesnt work!

I have worked with Foundation 5, and with some features you need to ensure you include the relevant javascript.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, no, now i add foundation.magellan.js but nothing change. What it can be?